# The program to stop working correctly windows will close and notify you if a solution is available

Tags: c#, server, runtime-error, winsock

I have a program in Visual Studio C#, when I run it in my pc , it always runs perfect, but when I run it in my client pc , it does not work correctly. shows a message box:

> A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will
> close the program and notify you if a solution is available

Server Form in C#

```
delegate void AddTextCallback(string text);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ButtonConnected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ServerHandler));
        }

        private void ServerHandler(object state)
        {
        try
        {
            TcpListener _listner = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("12.2.54.658"), 145);

            _listner.Start();

            AddText("Server started - Listening on port 145");

            Socket _sock = _listner.AcceptSocket();

            while (_sock.Connected)
            {
                byte[] _Buffer = new byte[1024];

                int _DataReceived = _sock.Receive(_Buffer);

                if (_DataReceived == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                AddText("Message Received...");

                string _Message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_Buffer);

                AddText(_Message);
            }

            _sock.Close();

            AddText("Client Disconnected.");

            _listner.Stop();

            AddText("Server Stop.");

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ServerHandler(ex.ToString());
        }
        }

        private void AddText(string text)
        {
            if (this.listBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                AddTextCallback d = new AddTextCallback(AddText);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(text);
            }
        }
```

Getting error in client pc

[image]

I'm trying to solve this for last 2 wks. But i didn't get any idea about it. Please Someone helps me to solve my problem.

Comment: Its likely that there is an exception thrown. Try putting a 'MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());' in front of 'ServerHandler(ex.ToString());'

Comment: Mosty likely you are missing some assemblies, which you have on your PC, but are different on your client's machine.

Comment: try checking the .net framework on client machine. also verify if all referenced assemblies exist in client machine. also verify if firewall is blocking your pogram to listen to the specific port

Comment: Also check that the target PC has the correct version of the .Net framework installed.

Comment: Thank u all for your comments. In  client pc all other project are open . but this server project is only the problem . I think here i use winsock control for receiving data . for that only i'm getting this issue i try to solve this for verifying the download items for winsock in my pc and also install it to client pc

Answer (score -1):

I opened the visual studio as an administrator after that
I've opened the App.config and inside the `<configuration>` wrote

```
<system.windows.forms jitDebugging="false"/>
```

after that, the program runs 100 % 100